# Is multiple login possible with firebase authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I develop some kind of website

This website requires multiple logins

So I asked this question.

> Is it possible for a website user to have multiple authentications
>   with one email account?

Is it possible to authenticate 100 devices with one ID?

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by "this website requires multiple logins".  What is the requirement here?

Comment: More than 10 devices log in with one ID and store the data.

Comment: Firebase Auth doesn't care how many devices a user can use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking to login with same credentials on multiple devices then it's possible.

But you can't create multiple user accounts with one email id.

Comment: Is it possible to create an account and get authentication from multiple devices?

Comment: Yes, definitely. I have a project wherein an Admin(It's one account) has to log in to multiple devices at the same time.